# event.preventDefault() isn't working on the form submit

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, es6-class

I am trying to submit the form but the page just get refresh after I hit the submit button and the `event.preventDefault()` doesn't seems to work.

```
class UI {
  constructor() {
    this.budgetForm = document.getElementById("budget-form");
  }

  //submit budget method
  budgetSubmitForm() {
    console.log('hello from es6');
  }
}

function eventListenters() {
  const budgetForm = document.getElementById("budget-form");
  const expenseForm = document.getElementById("expense-form");
  const expenseList = document.getElementById('expense-list');

  // New instance of UI class 
  const ui = new UI();
  // budgetForm submit 
  budgetForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    ui.budgetSubmitForm()
  });

  // expense form submit 
  expenseForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

// expense list click 
  expenseList.addEventListener('click', function() {
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', function() {
  eventListenters();
})
```

I will really appreciate someone helping me!

Comment: Please, please read the documentation for this site and learn to properly format your code so that people can read it.

Comment: is it fine now? Thank you for telling me!

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No, nothing it just navigate me to this page again Navigated to http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html?

Comment: Your `DOMcontentLoaded` should be `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: `document.addEventListener('DOMcontentLoaded', function() {
  eventListenters();
})` is redundant. Just use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', eventListenters);`

Comment: You should also provide the relevant HTML in your question.